# I need to filter all websites except for one

Tags: windows-7, web-filtering

My operating system is Windows 7 Starter.

I need a software solution, I'm well aware of the built in options of Windows 7, but the rules are no limited accounts, no accounts at all, something (a firewall?) able to block all HTTP traffic except the one coming from a single website. I've seen several solution (cyber nanny and the likes) but they are a bit expensive and full of features I'll never use.

I thought I could do it with the hosts file but it doesn't support wildcards. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Group Policy or [this alternative](http://malektips.com/internet_explorer_7_0037.html), you can lock people out of the settings of Internet Explorer.

Then, using [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) you could create a rule to block anything but the domain your user would access.

When creating your action file, read [about actions](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#ACTIONS) and [about block](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#BLOCK); it should be something like this:

```
{+block{Not allowed.}}
 *

{-block}
 *.yourdomain.com
```

It supports Wildcards but I could be wrong about the syntax, it's possible that [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are used.

Comment: Thank you, sadly proxy policies are browser enforced, I can just install chrome and bypass everything.

Comment: @0plus1: Makes sense, an administrator can always override.

Comment: @0plus1: Thinking about it, as I've been set up a DD-WRT router this weekend. You could use `iptables` on such a router to block all incoming information except for the IPs used by the website...